# Easy configurable javascript libraries to render sequence of month for 100 rows per page

Tags: javascript, calendar, cal-heatmap

I need to show up to 100 components similar to cal-heatmap calendar with year-month view. It seems that creation of 100 cal-heatmap per paginated table is not good idea due to performance.

The requirement is to show each resource availability within selected interval (eg. Feb15 - May 16) in table view.

What are the best configurable javascript libraries to render sequence of month for each row(100 rows per page).

```
{% for row in queryset %}
var cal{{ forloop.counter }} = new.CalHeatMap();
cal{{ forloop.counter }}.init(
          {id:"cal{{ forloop.counter }}", itemSelector: "#previousSelector-a", previousSelector: "#previousSelector-a-previous", domain: 'day', subDomain:'hour', colLimit: 24, range: 4, displayLegend: false, domainLabelFormat: ""}
);
{% endfor %}


....
{% for row in queryset %}
    <div id="cal{{ forloop.counter }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You haven't shown code, but if you are re-drawing the DOM after adding each element, this can slow down performance dramatically. Try building the elements first then add all 100 components in a single operation

Comment: I need to run similar code with queryset.size=100: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911767/multiple-calendars-on-same-page-with-cal-heatmap-plugin. Is it good idea to do like this with size=100 considering performance and that user can hit next page where we can render next 100 components.